# plot_trisurf unwanted triangle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with python and I am using matplotlib to create 3D graph however the `plot_trisurf` method keeps triangles on one edge of the graph and it is really annoying. I have looked for solution but did not succeed to solve the problem.
Here is the code:

```
variableToDisplay='U'

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_trisurf(X,Y,Z,cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.1)   
fig.colorbar(surf)  
fig.tight_layout()  
plt.show(block=False)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Do you try to delete points (2,4.5) and (5.5, 0.0001) which are produced uncorrected triangles?

Comment: First thank you very much for answering. When you delete those points there are just new triangles which appears and the thing is that I am doing a parametric simulation on a wind turbine blade and this graph is computed automatically from simulations and all points matters but I read it is something with triangulation but I couldnt implement something which solve the problem

Comment: Apparently with this Delaunay triangulation you can mask some triangles or just define a new way of triangulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a way. Here is the code and the graph obtained:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.tri as tri
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import os


isbad =np.greater(y, 4.88)
triang = tr.Triangulation(x, y)
mask = np.all(np.where(isbad[triang.triangles], True, False), axis=1)
triang.set_mask(mask)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(triang,Z,cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.1)
fig.colorbar(surf)
fig.tight_layout()
ax.set_xlabel('Position of debond (% of blade length)')
ax.set_ylabel('Size of debond')
ax.set_zlabel(variableToDisplay)
plt.show(block=False)
```

In the variable 'isbad' 4.88 refers to almost the maximum value of the y list so the triangles on that edge will be avoided

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnogB.png)